# Image doesn't show up on WPF tile

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, xaml, kinect

this code is from sample that is provided in Kinect for Windows developer kit 2.0. I want the pictures to cover the tiles, but its not working.

Here is Xaml code:

```
    <ItemsControl Grid.Row="0" Name="itemsControl" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Kinect350x350ItemTemplate}" Button.Click="ButtonClick
      <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
          <ItemsPanelTemplate>
             <WrapPanel VerticalAlignment="Center" Orientation="Vertical" Margin="75,0,75,0" />
          </ItemsPanelTemplate>
      </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
   </ItemsControl>
```

Here is my StaticResource Kinect350x350ItemTemplate

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="Kinect350x350ItemTemplate">
    <Button Margin="5" Style="{StaticResource KinectTileButton}">
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="350" Height="350">
            <Border Background="{StaticResource ListViewItemPlaceholderBackgroundThemeBrush}">
                <Image Source="{Binding Image}" Stretch="UniformToFill" AutomationProperties.Name="{Binding Title}"/>
            </Border>
            <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Background="{StaticResource ListViewItemOverlayBackgroundThemeBrush}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Foreground="{StaticResource ListViewItemOverlayForegroundThemeBrush}" Style="{StaticResource TitleTextStyle}" Height="60" Margin="15,0,15,0"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Subtitle}" Foreground="{StaticResource ListViewItemOverlaySecondaryForegroundThemeBrush}" Style="{StaticResource CaptionTextStyle}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Margin="15,0,15,10"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </Button>
</DataTemplate>
```

as I understand, this line doesn't show me the image:

```
    <Image Source="{Binding Image}" Stretch="UniformToFill" AutomationProperties.Name="{Binding Title}"/>
```

Here is the Data Model:

```
    private static Uri darkGrayImage = new Uri("thumbs/DarkGray.png", UriKind.Relative);
    private static Uri mediumGrayImage = new Uri("thumbs/mediumGray.png", UriKind.Relative);
    private static Uri lightGrayImage = new Uri("thumbs/lightGray.png", UriKind.Relative);
    private static Uri AUMImage = new Uri("thumbs/aum.jpg", UriKind.Relative);
    public KuwaitDataSource()
    {
        string itemContent = string.Format(
                                CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
                                "Item Content: {0}\n\n{0}\n\n{0}\n\n{0}\n\n{0}\n\n{0}\n\n{0}",
                                "Bla-Bla-Bla");

        var group1 = new KuwaitDataCollection(
                "Group-1",
                "Group Title: 3",
                "Group Subtitle: 3",
                KuwaitDataSource.AUMImage,
                "Group Description: Some text here.");
        group1.Items.Add(
                new SampleDataItem(
                    "Group-1-Item-1",
                    "Egaila",
                    "Egaila is a quite city to live. It has a great university AUM and big shopping centers.",
                    KuwaitDataSource.AUMImage,
                    "A map of Egaila, enabling scrolling and zooming.",
                    itemContent,
                    group1,
                    typeof(Egaila)));
           this.AllGroups.Add(group1);
    }
```

On the output I have only ListViewItemPlaceholderBackgroundThemeBrush, no image on it... What did I miss?

Comment: Are you populating that `ItemsControl` with anything? If so, what? Is it a collection of something that has an `Image` property of type `ImageSource`?

Comment: Yes, I'm populating that `ItemdControl` with  `Kinect350x350ItemTemplate` and it has and Image `<Image Source="{Binding Image}"..`  and the images comes from DataModel. @EdPlunkett

Comment: You're populating the ItemsControl with the data model class -- maybe. But you haven't shown that code. You can't populate anything with a template. That makes no sense.

Comment: Where is the Image property of the DATA MODEL? Where is the ImageSource? What are you binding to?

Comment: In my DATA MODEL I have `private static Uri AUMImage = new Uri("thumbs/aum.jpg", UriKind.Relative);` and then I put it into my Group-1. When MainWindows is loaded I call `var sampleDataSource = KuwaitDataSource.GetGroup("Group-1");`

Comment: I've got this code `public ImageSource Image
        {
            get
            {
                if (this.image == null && this.imagePath != null)
                {
                    this.image = new BitmapImage(new Uri(SampleDataCommon.baseUri, this.imagePath));
                }

                return this.image;
            }

            set
            {
                this.imagePath = null;
                this.SetProperty(ref this.image, value);
            }
        }`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126835/discussion-between-hurrem-and-ed-plunkett).

Comment: I have also 
`public ImageSource Image
        {
            get
            {
                if (this.image == null && this.imagePath != null)
                {
                    this.image = new BitmapImage(new Uri(SampleDataCommon.baseUri, this.imagePath));
                }

                return this.image;
            }

            set 
            {
                this.imagePath = null;
                this.SetProperty(ref this.image, value);
            }
        }`